# Custom user URL on root directory?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-location

I'm wanting to have a user profile on the root directory, as it's currently at example.com/u/User, I'm wanting example.com/User,

So I made this configuration:

```
location @extensionless-php {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }
  location @try-user {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1;
  }

    location / {
              try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php @try-user;
              # To do: try-page
              index index.html index.htm index.php;
              expires 1h;
              rewrite ^/messages/(.*)$ /messaging.php?u=$1;
    }
```

Whenever I go to any page with that configuration, it goes to @try-user, and when I type in my username (example.com/Phil), I'm getting a "User not found".

Could anyone help?

Comment: You cannot have two named locations on a `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). What URI are you trying to achieve - `/profile.php?user=/Phil` or `/profile.php?user=Phil` ?

Comment: /profile.php?user=Phil

Answer (score 0):

Your `try_files` statement is not strictly correct, as only the final term can be a named location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

`nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`. In your rewrite, you should avoid capturing the leading `/`, if you are trying to capture the user name.

For example:

```
location @try-user {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @try-user;
    ...
}
```

You might wish to have more than one `rewrite` statement, and order them so that patterns matching a username are redirected to `profile.php` whereas anything else is treated as a PHP file. For example:

```
location @try-user {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 last;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: I'm wanting extensionless PHP as-well with this, is that possible?

Comment: I was attempting to illustrate that in the second example. Obviously URIs like `/foo` will be interpreted as user names, whereas URIs like `/foo/bar` will be redirected to `/foo/bar.php`